# Interactions between levels -- how to interpret output?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I'm confused on how to interpret R output for interactions with multiple levels.

Here's what my output looks like for my full model:

```
Fixed effects:
                  Estimate   Std. Error     df t value   Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       0.91795    0.01388 167.89793  66.140   <2e-16 ***
group2            0.00130    0.01963 167.89793   0.066   0.9473    
group3            0.01414    0.01963 167.89793   0.721   0.4721    
session2         -0.02387    0.01243 441.31058  -1.921   0.0554 .  
group2:session2  -0.03859    0.01757 441.31058  -2.196   0.0286 *  
group3:session2  -0.01688    0.01757 441.31058  -0.961   0.3372
```

At first glance, I thought there was a significant interaction between Group and Session.

Then I ran an Anova on my model:

```
Anova(Mod12,type="II",test.statistic="Chisq")
```

Here's the output:

```
Response: accuracy
            Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
group          1.9873  2     0.3702    
session       34.8702  1  3.524e-09 ***
group:session  4.8495  2     0.0885 .
```

I interpreted this Anova output as aggregating the interactions between levels, so my overall Group:Session interaction is NOT significant.

Would my group2:session2 be considered a pairwise comparison?

Comment: What do you mean pairwise comparison? `group2:session2` is the interaction term relating to these two factors. While `group:session` is for all the groups and sessions combined.

Comment: @user2974951 I just don't know how to interpret group2:session2. I thought it meant that group 2 performed significantly different at session 2 compared to session 1, but I don't think this is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, from the ANOVA table you get an insignificant result for the interaction term `group:session` as a whole (`group:session, pvalue=0.0885`, although I don't know why you used type II SS), so you should not interpret any of the interaction terms in your linear model, even though some of them are significant.

Second, if you were to interpret the interaction terms, then you need to understand how R deals with contrasts. See an introductory textbook on linear models for this.

In short: the term `session2` is the estimated slope for `group1`. The term `group2:session2` is the estimated difference in the slope of `group2`, so the slope for `group2` is equal to `-0.02387 + (-0.03859)` which is significantly different from the slope of `group1`. So the individuals in `group2` react differently to `session2` than the individuals in `group1`.

Comment: thanks so much for your input. I used type II SS because when I was looking up ways to use the Anova function, this one was the one being used. I didn't know too much about the difference between I, II and III, but my data is balanced, so I assumed it didn't make a difference.